# How to multiply 2 matrices with a 1d array representation?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am writing a program that will read a matrix from a file with the following format:

```
2 3
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

To which I will represent using a 1D array (also containing the dimensions, so the resulting array would be:

```
A: {2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Now, I am to multiply this matrix by another one, with the same format. I am aware of how to multiply two matrices, my only issue is in the actual writing. I am unsure what I am doing wrong, as when I walk through the steps, it seems logical, but clearly that is not the case.

Below is the method where I attempt to multiply the two matrices:

```
void multiply(double *A, double *B){
    double *C=malloc(B[1]*A[0]*sizeof *C);

    int a_rows=A[0];
    int a_cols=A[1];
    int b_rows=B[0];
    int b_cols=B[1];

    printf("ar: %d, ac: %d, br: %d bc: %d\n", a_rows, a_cols, b_rows, b_cols);
    int l = 0;
    double val = 0;
    for(int i=2;i<b_rows+2;i++){
        for(int j=2;j<b_cols+2;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<a_cols;k++){
                val=val+A[i*b_cols+k]*B[b_rows*b_rows+j];
            }
            C[l]=val;
            l++;
            val = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<b_cols*a_rows;i++){
        printf("%d: %f\n",i, C[i]);
    }
    free(C);
}
```

Now, I believe I must have made a mistake in my indexing, but at the moment it is beyond me.

Comment: You need to start the loops at 0 and add 2 to skip the dimensions.

Comment: Based on (e.g) `A: {2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` you're putting the array dimensions in the first two elements. Here's a macro to index into the arrays: `#define ARROF(_arr,_row,_col) _arr[2 + ((_row) * _arr[1]) + (_col)]`